# Make salesforce lightning lookups more useable

Tags: lightning, lookup, search

I'm running into a few inconveniences with lightning lookup search and want to know how to make this better.

I have a filtered lookup on an object to another object and currently, there are 3 major complaints we frequently get

1. Users have to type at least 3 characters for it to begin searching and returning results
2. There does not seem to be an ability to do a blank search where it returns a list of records for the object in the lookup with no query
3. There does not seem to be a way to remove the "+ New Object" quick action

The only seemingly way to use Lookup Search is to know what you're searching for in advance by using a list view on the object itself and this seems counterintuitive.

Are any of these issues addressable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, this is all the expected behavior with the standard field within the standard layout/detail page. For each point, I included the idea you can upvote

1. Didn't find an exact one, but this one regards [utilizing wildcard character in search](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DyYyAAK) that might be similar enough.
2. [Show all records in lookup search](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxgoAAA)
3. [Disable Quick Create New Button on lookup window in Lightning](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TvUBQA0)

In terms of workarounds outside of building your own, process might help you. Without full context, it's hard to suggest - but, depending on your situation

#1 & #2 - seems to stem from users not necessarily knowing what they need to search for or what record they want. It might make more sense for them to utilize "global search" to find the record (or maybe some known parent record) and then you have an action/screen flow to help them work "backwards" to update the record related to it.

#3 - If you can't remove the create permission from the profile, I'd presume you want to remove it due to potential for data quality concerns? Validation rules or duplicate rules could help to prevent bad data from being created.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, No.

But you can always choose to customize your own look up field.

Using a open-source Lookup Components built by lwc is a good way to go.

[sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc) is probably the most powerful lookup component so far and me myself is using it, too.

Comment: Can you embed this in the same position as the OOB lookups on a standard lightning record detail page?

Comment: @TemporaryFix I'm afraid that is not possible. Instead I have to write an entire detail page  using lightning-record-edit-form, and embed this in the form. The look will stay the same. The cost is time and not able to change fields in record-layout page.